# opengl mouse interaction checkbox

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, graphics, logic

I am trying to create a checkbox from scratch and I am having some problems.

In my control.h file I initialized

```
public : int checked = 0;
```

So whenever the mouse presses the correct area, `checked` will become one. 
And the drawCheckBox method will check if it is 1 or 0, and put a check on the box. 
The program runs, however when I press the box area, and check what value `checked` is, it keeps showing 0. I'm not sure why though.

drawing the checkbox / checking if user checked

```
// Function to generate food selection box in left selection area.
void Control::drawCheckBox(string food, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    //placement of the check box
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glRectf(x1, y1, x2,y2);

    // Draw black boundary.
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glLineWidth(5);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glRectf(x1, y1, x2, y2);


    if (checked == 1)checker(x1, y1, x2, y2); // checks the check box.
    else glColor3f(1, 1, 1);                        
    cout << checked;


}
```

mouse callback routine

```
// The mouse callback routine.
void mouseControl(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    Control check;
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)

        // Store the clicked point in the points array after correcting
        // from event to OpenGL co-ordinates.
        //points.push_back(Point(x, height - y));

        if ((x >= 5 && x <= 10) && (y <= 85 && y >= 80))
        {
        if (check.checked == 1)
        {
            check.checked = check.checked - 1;
        }
        else check.checked++;
        }

    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) exit(0);

        glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

Comment: Does `mouseControl()` get called only when the mouse state changes or will it get called every frame (ie continually called while the user is holding down the mouse). You might consider using braces for all your if statements otherwise it's easy to run code that you don't expect.

Comment: From the code you have, `Control check;` never gets instantiated and only exists in the scope of your mouseControl function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are declaring an object of 
 `Control check;` 
 locally in the `mouseControl()` function. 
I presume your `Control` constructor is initializing the `Control::checked` state to `0`. 
Hence, you would always see the value of `Control::checked` to be `0`.

You need to decide the scope and lifetime of your `Control check` object.
Hope this will help in fixing the issue. 

Otherwise, it will help if you post more code, especially the complete `Control` class implementation and where and how the `mouseControl` is being called. 

Then we can figure out how it should be done.